# Subsets which are "never closed" under group operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I am wondering if there are some specific properties of groups for which there exists nonempty subset, say $\exists X\ne\emptyset,X\subset G$, s. t. $\forall g,h\in X$, its product $gh$ does not belongs to $X$. I didn't find any references where such pairs $(G,X)$ will be discussed. Under what name (in the literature) should I look for such subsets, or group which possesses them? I am interested in study properties of such objects (under additional assumptions) and looking for some references. As an example it will be interesting to know when such pairs can exists, how large $X$ can be, how many such $X$s are possible for a given group $G$, if $(G,X)$ is such a pair, for which subgroup $H$ of $G$, $(H,X)$ also have this property etc.

I will be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: Such exists for all nontrivial groups: Let $X$ consist of any single nonidentity element.

Comment: @Berci, but can we say e.g. how many of such $X$ can exist, how large they can be etc.?

Comment: I was looking in the literature, but couldn't find some more detailed analysis for such pairs, so I am asking for any overview/literature where such problems can be found.

Comment: Well, these might be interesting questions. Nevertheless, as currently formulated, the class of groups you ask about is just all nontrivial groups.

Comment: @Berci, right - I will edit it and add more specific quesions also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called *sum-free sets* and are a central topic in additive combinatorics where people study exactly the kind of questions that you mention.

See for example the paper [Sum-free sets in abelian groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307142.pdf) by Ben Green and Imre Ruzsa.